# Connecting to remote PostgreSQL server using Java JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, remote-desktop

I am writing a Java program from my local machine where I am supposed to extract defects data from Bugzilla, and the data is stored in a PostgreSQL DB in remote desktop. I can't seem to connect to my PostgreSQL server that is hosted in Windows remote desktop connection. I have already imported PostgreSQL jar to my project.

This is my code:

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres";
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Is there anything I need to do on my remote desktop? I have 3 IP addresses (as well as remote instance ID and hostname) if that'll help:

```
Remote Public IP Address : xx.xxx.xxx.123
Remote Private IP Address : xx.x.x.12
PostgreSQL Server in remote : localhost;port 5432
```

Comment: Have you checked that you can connect to the remote up address and port number through other means (I.e. console)

Comment: @synapticloop I can only successfully ping the remote public up address through cmd prompt

Comment: It could be a firewall in your way - or a different port number - from your machine `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 8.8.8.8 -Port 53` if on windows, `nc -vz 10.xxx.xxx.xx0 9443` if on mac

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing.  Databases cannot be hosted inside an RDP connection.  Are you trying to use RDP to tunnel the connection?

Comment: @jjanes I have a postgresql DB that is hosted in the RDP. I am writing a java program from my local machine where I am supposed to extract defects data from bugzilla, and the datas are stored in postgresql DB

Comment: PostgreSQL cannot be hosted in RDP.  It can be hosted by a computer which you can use RDP to connect to and administer, but the database is not inside RDP.  Maybe you can use RDP to open a tunnel you can use to connect through, like you can with ssh--I don't know.  But hosting the database in RDP just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jjanes does it make sense if i say that i connect to my IP in RDP, once i am inside, i can access postgresql. So basically I am like accessing my postgresql hosted in the VM.

Comment: `localhost` is **your** machine. You can't use it to connect to a database located on another machine (at least not without explicitly setting up a tunnel). You need to specify the hostname of the remote machine (and that assumes the port is even open on the associated IP address and not filtered/blocked by a firewall).